# Apply gradient or solid color on dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to apply a gradient or a solid color to an element with jquery. Why with jQuery? Because this site has several different color combo's so generating css classes is too much work.

Let's say I have this list generated from a JSON call

```
<div class="colours">
 <ul>
  <li class="black white"></li>
  <li class="green"></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see I need one list element with a gradient (black/white) and one solid (green) element.

**So my question is how to set either a gradient when a list class has two colors in it or a solid color when just one color is needed??**

With my code below it always gives me "productHtml is not a function" or `[object object]` when I try to apply the colors.

```
$.each(data.product.custom, function(i, custom) {

        var productsHtml = [];
        $.each(custom.values, function(index, value){
          var color = (value.title).toLowerCase();

          var colorClean = color.replace(/\s?\/\s?/," ");
          var colors = colorClean.split(/\s+/);
          if (colors.length===1) {
            colors[1] = colors[0];
          }

       // var productHtml = '' +
       //        '<li class="'+colorClean+'" ></li>';

         var productHtml = $('<li></li>').css({ 
            'background': '-moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  + colors[0] + 0%, + colors[0] + 49%, + colors[1] + 49%, + colors[1] + 100%)',
            //etc etc
        });
          productsHtml.push(productHtml);
        });
        productsHtml = productsHtml.join('');

        $('.product.'+id+' .colours').html('<ul>'+productsHtml+'</ul>');

      });
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that your string (`'-moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  + colors[0] + 0%, + colors[0] + 49%, + colors[1] + 49%, + colors[1] + 100%)'`) is the problem; you need to concatenate the variables with the string (to give: `'-moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,'  + colors[0] + ' 0%', + colors[0] + '49%,' + colors[1] + '49%', + colors[1] + '100%)'`)

Comment: why are you using `,` in the last of the line `background`

Comment: Variables inside hyphens will not be evaluated by Javascript. Use string concatenation `+`.

Comment: This looks so much more painful than editing, extending or resetting the css.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using the data-attribute.

1. First I iterate over all **<li>** elements in **.colours**.
2. Then find its **data-colour** attribute.
3. Create a string with the necessary linear-gradient info.
4. Adding **all** the colours (separated by ",") in its data attribute.
5. Closing the linear-gradient info string.
6. applying the linear-gradient to a css rule with `css()`.

**note** It can have any colour value:

- `data-colour("rgb(255,123,43)");`
- `data-colour("#222 #546");`
- `data-colour("rgb(2,150,255) #3a1");`

```js
$(".colours").find('li').each(function(index, e) {
  var $elem = $(e);
  var colourattri = $(this).data("colour");
  var colours = colourattri.split(",");

  if (colours.length >= 2) {
    var linear = "linear-gradient(90deg, ";

    for (var index in colours) {
      linear += colours[index];
      if (index != colours.length - 1) {
        linear += ", ";
      }
    }
    linear += ")";
    $elem.css({
      background: linear,
    });
  } else if (colours.length == 1) {
    $elem.css("background-color", colours[0]);
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="colours">
  <ul>
    <li data-colour="black">Some text here</li>
    <li data-colour="black, white">Some text here</li>
    <li data-colour="red, blue">Some text here</li>
    <li data-colour="pink, white">Some text here</li>
    <!-- This can take a lot of colours-->
    <li data-colour="red, Orange, green, blue, indigo, violet">Some text here</li>
    <li data-colour="rgb(22,150,255), red, #2c3">Some text here</li>
    <li data-colour="rgb(22,150,255) 50%, red 60%, #2c3 90%">Some text here</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok this is exactly what I was looking for! There's only one thing... Is it possible to set eg 50% white and 50% black? So you'll get the same as a normal css rule `linear-gradient(135deg,  #000000 0%,#000000 49%,#ffffff 49%,#ffffff 100%);`

Comment: Did you try it yet? oh well i guess I'll update it for you

Comment: Yes code works perfectly the only thing is that it needs to be 50% of each color instead of a real gradient ;)

Comment: There now it splits on "," instead of " " (space).

Comment: Ok I understand what you did (I think) ;)... The colours that you grab from the classnames are eg "black" etc... My previous question actually was how can I add 50% to that classname(s) so that it reads `linear-gradient(135deg, #000000 0%,#000000 49%,#ffffff 49%,#ffffff 100%);`?? I can't add that myself since the classnames are generated dynamically...

Comment: If your going to add percentages then it gets really tricky and hacky if your going to add it to the class. Please add it to a data-attribute instead.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading each color individually and then applying your gradient / solid color logic.  Like:

```
$('li').each(function(){
    var classNames = $(this).attr("class").toString().split(' ');
    $.each(classNames, function (i, className) {
        // do solid color or gradient
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't fully understand... The classnames are generated dynamically??! Or is this a "function" you do after the json call...Can you explain a liitle more?

Comment: No, it's just looping through the class names in each list item.